# Right click-Properties don't work on anything

Tags: windows-10

I upgraded Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. Arfter that right click-properties menu don't work. Can I fix this. I don't want re-install the Windows 10. Because I have dozens of Programs and config on Windows.

Edit: The menu is showing. I can click but after click doesn't appear anything. Only cursor shows busy indicator for a second.

Comment: Do you mean that the properties option in the right-click menu doesn't appear or that it is visible but clicking it doesn't do anything or do you mean something else? Could you please upload a screenshot/s to show this behaviour by editing your question?

Comment: @LJD200 thank you. I edited the question.

Comment: Does running `sfc /scannow` fix it (this command scans and repairs corrupted Windows system files - [see this MS article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/929833))?

Comment: Does it work while in Safe Mode?

Comment: I resolved this issue. I installed Yandex.Disk before. In the Event Viewer logs there is an Application Error about Yandex Disk Shell. I uninstalled it and problem fixed.

Comment: @huseyindotpw Could you please add your comment as a solution and mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue. I installed Yandex.Disk before. In the Event Viewer logs there is an Application Error about Yandex Disk Shell. I uninstalled it and problem fixed.